# Why can't I add support library in Android Studio?

Tags: android

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.8.+'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.+'
    compile 'com.github.chrisbanes.actionbarpulltorefresh:library:+'
    compile 'com.actionbarsherlock:actionbarsherlock:4.4.0@aar'
    compile project(':library:SlidingMenu:library')
    compile project(':library:Android-ViewPagerIndicator:library')
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
}

apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}
```

Event Log

Failed to refresh Gradle project 'My Application' Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.0.+] on project ':app'. Please install the Android Support Repository from the Android SDK Manager.

[image]